# Publishing error: dotnet.exe failed

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, publishing

I was gifted a .net core 1.0 app when the original author quit. It was written back in rc1-rc2... We have since updated the project to use the latest core 1.0.0 and it compiles and runs locally on my dev machine (win 7) but when publishing, in any manner, I cannot get it to stand up.

I tried pub to local directory and copy it over, tried publish via 'web deploy', only ever get:

> OOPS! 500 error. An error occurred while starting the application.

ALSO, 
Every time I try to publish I get this error when viewing the 'settings' tab in the publish wizard.
It seems to error every time it does 'Discovering Data Contexts'.

What could be wrong? Upon build it also gives me some info: "No web.config found. Creating 'C:\Users\bdamore\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp\LogManager.Web115\web.config'"... but there IS a web.config in the project... ???

> Problem signature:
>     Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
>     Application Name: dotnet.exe
>     Application Version:  1.0.1.4500
>     Application Timestamp:    576218d2
>     Fault Module Name:    KERNELBASE.dll
>     Fault Module Version: 6.1.7601.23455
>     Fault Module Timestamp:   573a54fc
>     Exception Code:   e0434352
>     Exception Offset: 000000000001a06d
>     OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
>     Locale ID:    1033
>     Additional Information 1: 703e
>     Additional Information 2: 703e0160aed03e454ba0c593b0d130bd
>     Additional Information 3: 9077
>     Additional Information 4: 907774a39ea215c56d3fe4e6094e8d07

[image: blows up here]

Comment: Can you try `dotnet publish` CLI to check if (by chance) you get a more useful error message?

Comment: Are you sure you are still logged in to Azure in VS? I saw a similar crash when I was logged off over the weekend. Also, are you running VS 2015 Update 3 with the latest Azure SDK?

Comment: @GerardoGrignoli I apparently am using the dotnet publish CLI. FYI, I am not using Azure, this is local.

Comment: VS2015 Update 3, yes. newest .net everything, yes

Comment: You may have to post your project.json, may be difficult to give you a concrete answer w/o guessing

Comment: @Beau I meant you go to CMD, then CD to the same folder where `project.json` is and run `dotnet publish` (you will need to figure which parameters to pass). And check the error message. My guess is that it may throw a more useful error message.

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the necessary files to the folder where your application is built/published. In the project.json you have a section named

```
"publishOptions": {
  "include": [
    "wwwroot",
    "Views",
    "web.config",
    "hosting**.json",
    "appsettings**.json" 
  ]
}
```

and the `web.config` needs to be located in the project root, not in `wwwroot`. With one of the RC candidates, the application entry point got moved from `wwwroot` to project/application root folder.

Comment: did you mean `wwwroot` and not `wwwdata`?

Comment: Yes, my project.json has those entries in it. I will post the relevant files.

Answer (score 0):

in my project.json, I had to change

'tools' :   "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-*"

to

'tools :   "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0"

(removed the '-*')